# Extending Highmaps Side Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, geojson

I am trying to create a dot density map of the state of Florida. While I know that Highmaps doesn't support color axis with mappoints. I extended it and it works but it comes with a side affect. When I click on one of the categories in the legend no hiding occurs. For example if I click on '>10', all values greater than 10 don't hide. When I open up the Chrome debugger it states that: **a.setVisible is not a function** What can I do to solve this problem. This is a requirement, while it may seem minor. I would appreciate any sort of tips or maybe some sort of example would be perfect. I can't show more code than what is shown. If you need me to explain more about the problem I will be glad to do so.

```
               (function (H) {
                    H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype.axisTypes = [ 'xAxis', 'yAxis', 'colorAxis'];
                    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype, "translate", function (p) {
                        p.call(this);
                        H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype.translateColors.call(this);
                    });
                    H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype.translateColors = H.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.translateColors;
                    H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype.colorKey = 'value';

                })(Highcharts);


                // Initiate the chart
                $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
                    title: {
                        text: title
                    },
                    mapNavigation: {
                        enabled: false,
                    },
                    colorAxis: {
                        dataClasses: [{
                                from: 0,
                                to: 3,
                                color: "#66FFFF"
                            }, {
                                from: 4,
                                to: 9,
                                color: "#0099FF"
                            }, {
                                from: 10,
                                color: "#0000FF"
                            }
                            ]
                    },
                    tooltip:
                            {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                    ,
                    series: [{
                            mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/us/us-fl-all'],
                            name: 'Basemap',
                            borderColor: '#A0A0A0',
                            nullColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3)',
                            showInLegend: false,
                        },
                        {
                            // Specify points using lat/lon
                            type: 'mappoint',
                            name: 'A',
                            turboThreshold: 2000000,
                            data: p_data,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            // Specify points using lat/lon
                            type: 'mappoint',
                            name: 'B',
                            turboThreshold: 2000000,
                            data: m_data,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false

                            }
                        },
                        {
                            // Specify points using lat/lon
                            type: 'mappoint',
                            name: 'C',
                            turboThreshold: 2000000,
                            data: h_data,
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false

                            }
                        }



                    ]});
```

A sample to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/dlope073/4mabw6zr/2/

Comment: can you set up a live example?

Comment: I am going to try to put a sample jsFiddle code example.

Comment: @jlbriggs I put a jsFiddle. Click on the legend, notice how it doesn't disappear.

Comment: Ah. Well, when you click the legend, it's looking for a connected series to show or hide.  Your legend entries don't correspond to an actual series, so there is no entity for it to show or hide...  not sure the overall solution here, but would probably involve creating a dummy series for the high level, and using the linkedTo property of the individual series to tie to the group in the legend...?

Comment: Yeah I knew the problem but I don't know how to do it and Highmaps documentation isn't exactly clear on how to solve it but thanks for the help.

Comment: How about copying `setVisible` method from default map? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4mabw6zr/3/ - btw, you could told [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577443/highcharts-density-dot-map-support) you need to use `dataClasses` in colorAxis, it would be faster ;)

Comment: Pawel Fus can you write that as your answer it solves my question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setVisible` method from default `map` series. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4mabw6zr/3

```
(function (H) {
    H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype.axisTypes = ['xAxis', 'yAxis', 'colorAxis'];   
    H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype.pointClass.prototype.setVisible = H.seriesTypes.map.prototype.pointClass.prototype.setVisible; // use the same setVisible method as map type.

    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype, "translate", function (p) {
        p.call(this);
        H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype.translateColors.call(this);
    });
    H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype.translateColors = H.seriesTypes.heatmap.prototype.translateColors;
    H.seriesTypes.mappoint.prototype.colorKey = 'value';
})(Highcharts);
```