# How to make Highcharts color axis as thresholds instead of gradual?

Tags: highcharts

Referring to this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/heatmap/

where the color change is defined in the colorAxis:

```
        colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
    },
```

The color change is gradual in this case. How to set it as several thresholds?
For example, I want three thresholds:

<=100: green #00FF00

100~200: orange #FF8000

>=200: red #FF0040

How should I define the colorAxis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dataClasees` in your `colorAxis`:

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/uwrtts2k/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis.dataClasses

Comment: It seems the show-and-hide function by clicking the legend is not working. I've searched and it seems to be a bug (not sure). Do you have any idea to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: See if the answer here is useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713034/extending-highmaps-side-effect#comment49486912_30713034